# How to load string data in compile time in flash?

Tags: flash-builder

I wrote a string "return" in the text property field of a TextArea control in my mxml source code.Then I  got an error message saying you need an identifier before "return".
I think I need to load the string containing  "return" from a text file at compile time.

Do I?If yes then how can I load a string from a text file at compile time?
My flash builder is of version 4.5.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A snippet of your code would help.  Not sure what the problem is.